# Test for significant difference between two groups measured across time

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, statistical-significance, anova, t-test

I have two groups of time-dependent samples whose measured value changes nonlinearly with time. There are 3 samples in group A and 3 samples in group B. An example of my data is illustrated below.

**What test would be appropriate to test whether group A is significantly different from group B?**

As I seek the difference between group A and B and not the difference with time within each group, repeated measures ANOVA seems inappropriate. A mixed effects model would assume a linear change with time which does not apply here.

**Plot - Data example**

[image: Time-dependent samples in two groups]

**CSV - Data example**

```
Time,A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3
5,3.792645248,3.767412383,6.019934357,3.769078828,3.786871737,3.791214992
15,7.108624225,6.249444518,7.238739905,10.23524606,8.34298326,6.919577624
30,9.977429073,7.35986553,7.699815947,15.9001795,8.957144807,9.45955481
45,18.27403355,10.24380397,10.43652988,19.87898547,13.7122255,15.55478974
60,21.9362587,12.24045884,12.31885174,32.57894138,18.58268892,20.89684399
120,29.05427975,15.9553454,22.9201366,43.07367874,28.54766295,28.91710726
240,64.45944021,35.70624466,37.24061192,49.0052434,33.33309831,34.73066486
360,42.96420598,41.85475335,46.22951279,37.31929087,44.97518965,51.67423842
1440,54.9920728,57.90045856,48.82031436,48.48340553,44.9722854,51.46751176
1800,65.36311707,67.55856177,54.93558162,55.45770116,50.27138823,59.34195015
```

Answer (score 1):

Mixed effects models can still have a nonlinear function of time, e.g., a spline function in time as a fixed effect.  But random effects [usually don't capture the correct correlation pattern](https://fharrell.com/post/re) in longitudinal data.  A serial correlation model is usually better.  See [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/long) for a comprehensive example illustrating both of those concepts.  You can also combine serial correlation structure with a mixed model.

A general alternative is [Markov models](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/markov) which handle continuous, ordinal, nominal, and binary response variables.

Comment: Thanks, Frank! I'll check these out.

Do think mixed ANOVA could also be used - time as within-subjects factor and group (A/B) as between-subjects factor?

Comment: In a mixed effects longitudinal model time is still a fixed effect just like any covariate, and you have random intercepts and possibly random slopes for within-subject correlation over time.  The correlation assume by this, unless you also add in a serial correlation pattern, is unlikely to fit the data as described in a link above.